# How to set the retain period of Files Share snapshot with scheduler by Azure Automation?

Tags: azure, snapshot, azure-automation, fileshare

I want to set the retention period of Files Share snapshot with scheduler by Azure Automation.                                                                        1, May I set the schedule of creating and deleting the snapshot at one runbook. (like create one snapshot at today and delete it after one month).                         2, I want to get some snapshots by every day, week and month, can I decide the retain time. (Like keep the daily snapshot 15 days, the weekly snapshot 35days, and the Monthly snapshot 13months).
3, If it is so difficult, may I decide the snapshots that I want to delete, like the previous 10.                                                                         If you know something about that, please write some comments below, thanks so much.

Comment: Could you include more details in your question? What have you tried?

Comment: Thanks, Joy Wang. I add some comments, if you know something about that, please write some comments at here. Thank u again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some information for you to refer.

Try the command below to create snapshot, for its operating frequency, you could [create a schedule for the runbook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-schedules#creating-a-schedule).

```
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection"
try
{
    # Get the connection "AzureRunAsConnection "
    $servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         

    "Logging in to Azure..."
    Add-AzureRmAccount `
        -ServicePrincipal `
        -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId `
        -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId `
        -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint 
}
catch {
    if (!$servicePrincipalConnection)
    {
        $ErrorMessage = "Connection $connectionName not found."
        throw $ErrorMessage
    } else{
        Write-Error -Message $_.Exception
        throw $_.Exception
    }
}

$SAResourceGroupName="joywebapp"
$StorageAccountName="joystoragev2"
$StorageAccountKey = (Get-AzureRmStorageAccountKey -ResourceGroupName $SAResourceGroupName -AccountName $StorageAccountName).Value[1]
$context=New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName $StorageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $StorageAccountKey

$share = Get-AzureStorageShare -Context $context -Name "111"
$snapshot = $share.Snapshot()
```

Delete the snapshots created before one month:

```
$allsnapshots = Get-AzureStorageShare -Context $context | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq "111" -and $_.IsSnapshot -eq $true }


foreach($snapshot in $allsnapshots){
    if($snapshot.SnapshotTime -lt (get-date).AddMonths(-1)){
        $snapshot.Delete()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, Just now I had a try to delete the snapshots use the command you put upside. But all of the snapshots had been deleted, may I use one powershell to create a snapshot and then just delete that one after one month.

Comment: And last time someone shared a command to create snapshot, are there have some difference?                                                                                                $context = New-AzureStorageContext -StorageAccountName your_storage_account -StorageAccountKey your_storage_account_key
$share = Get-AzureStorageShare -Context $context -Name your_file_share_name             $snapshot = $share.Snapshot()

Comment: @Arthur 1.It should work, I test with `if($snapshot.SnapshotTime -lt (get-date).AddHours(-1))` to delete the snapshots created before an hour, it works fine, modify the `AddHours` to `AddMonths`, it should delete the snapshots created before one month.

Comment: @ Joy Wang, Thanks so much, I test it with one hour too, I combine the create and delete command in one powershell, it can work, but it deleted another snapshot (The previous one), so I think maybe it's because of the create command (I used your command, but there have some error about "$SAResourceGroupName" and "Value[1], so I used the easy one that I posted upside).

Comment: @Arthur Not sure why you got an error, all work fine on my side, and I test create and delete in two different runbooks, you could have a try.

Comment: Do you know how to delete a appoint snapshot, like just delete the snapshot after 1 month which I create today, but have no effects of other snapshots, because I will keep the different snapshots with the different retained periods.

Comment: I tired made them in one runbook, it can work well. Now I want to change the command "$allsnapshots" to the one I created before. But there has an error, I am not good at the cmdlets.  Thanks so much, Joy.

Comment: @Arthur This seems difficult to achieve, Snapshots can only be distinguished by `SnapshotTime`, my workaround is creating a snapshot, and get its `SnapshotTime`, new a runbook with a schedule to delete it after one month.

Comment: @Arthur May be you could ask the specific question of deleting snapshots with different ways in another post, if my reply is helpful, could you accept it as the answer?

Comment: Hi, I have some question want to check with you. yesterday you said you test with  **  if($snapshot.SnapshotTime -lt (get-date).AddHours(-1)) to delete the snapshots created before an hour, it works fine. **  So it's mean this command is used to delete the snapshots create before an hour, not delete a new one then delete it after an hour, right? I test and found it will delete all of the existing snapshots rather than delete some snapshot after hours or months.  Can you explain it? thanks

Comment: @Arthur Yes, is used to delete the snapshots create before an hour. I test the create and delete in two different runbooks, it will just delete the snapshots created before an hour, not all the screenshots. Not sure why it occurred to you.

Comment: sorry, I made a mistake. can you change your answer? Maybe it is better to say "Delete the snapshots created before one month:", thanks.

Comment: @Arthur Done, seems a little difference between them.